# Get Session value based on ajax success

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP page that uses a jQuery ajax call.

After I execute my AJAX and return a value on success, I need to use this value to pull an item from a PHP array, stored in session and update my SPAN with the new set.

Here's what I've got so far. I tested and I do return correct **data** value. I guess my syntax in jQuery is off, because my original span fades out, but nothing comes back.

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({ 
    ...
},
success: function(data){
    var nextItem = <?php echo $_SESSION['items'][data]->desc; ?>
    $('.x').fadeOut();
    $('.x').attr(id, data); 
    $('.x').text(nextItem).fadeIn();    
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<span id="'.$_SESSION['items'][0]->id.'" class="x">'.$_SESSION['items'][0]->desc.'</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the session variable in the AJAX call. Execute the PHP code to get the session variable on the URL your AJAX call is hitting. The response of the AJAX call (in this case the 'data' variable in your success function) will be the result of:

```
<?php echo $_SESSION['items'][data]->desc; ?>
```

So no PHP code will be in your JS.

If you need to return multiple values, then you might consider using JSON. Your AJAX processing page might be like:

```
$result = array('id' => $id, 'session' => $_SESSION['items'][$id]->desc);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Your JS might look like this:

```
$("#getJSON").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data) {
            $obj = $.parseJSON(data);
            console.log($obj[0].id, $obj[0].session);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused. Do you mean I need to compile my entire span in the page that processes my AJAX and return it all together as data? What if I need to update something else on the pagfe based on this success? Can I return multiple values, kind of like when I sent to AJAX, in JSON format?

Comment: OK, I know I marked it as "answered" but as it turns out, I'm still lost. How do I get each part of the array back on my original page?..